# How to sort the indicators

Tags: unity, indicator

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and I was wondering if is there any way to sort the indicators like this(Image):

[image: ubuntu's indicator]

The bottom bar is the default one and the upper bar is how I'd like to sort 'em.

```
 dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=com.canonical.indicator.application /com/canonical/indicator/application/service com.canonical.indicator.application.service.GetApplications | grep "object path"
```

returns this:

```
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/lang_indicator/Menu"
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/My_Weather_Indicator/Menu"
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/transmission/Menu"
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/bluetooth_manager/Menu"
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/indicator_sysmonitor/Menu"
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/nm_applet/Menu"
```

How I have to edit the "~/.local/share/indicators/application/ordering-override.keyfile" to do this?